# How to expand previously initialized memory size?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

```
int main()
{
    int *memory = new int[5];

    cout << "Memory starts at: " << &memory[0]; // 0x56225460beb0

    memory = new int[10];

    cout << "\nMemory starts at: "<< &memory[0]; // 0x56225460c2e0
                                                //   different
    cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to expand the previously initialized memory in C++, when initialized with `new`. Code above ends up creating a new memory location for `memory`. Does it also mean that previously allocated memory ends up taking space in my memory, because I didn't `delete` it

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it does reallocation as well. So not expanding the previous memory.

Comment: There is no reallocation going on in the OP's code, only memory leaks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but the question is about `is there a way to expand the previously initialized memory`. And his concern is different starting memory addresses.

Comment: @aep With vectors reallocation only occurs when necessary, i.e. when expanding is not possible. If it is not possible then there is no way to do it. Which means there cannot be any syntax or call which ensures expanding and gurantees not to reallocate.

Comment: @eap how would you "expand the previous memory" without reallocation?

Comment: @JesperJuhl If there happens to be free space right after the previously allocated memory then it is possible - and done in case of vectors.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, you basically can't guarantee in C++ with std::vectors.

Comment: @Yunnosch, is there a way to fix the size of a vector, so that I can expand it later when I want to, but before expanding it, it gives me error if I ```push_back``` out of bounds.

Comment: What do you mean by "fix the size of a vector"?

Comment: What do you mean by "previously initialized memory"?

Comment: @PrateekParashar -- What problem are you really trying to solve?  This is turning into an  [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, **problem: Make an array that doubles in size everytime it gets full and copy all elements of last array into this new array.** I was just wondering if I don't have to reinitialize a new space every time for this, and delete the last one, also it will prevent copying old elements.

Comment: You cannot expand `std::array`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::vector`, which for the most part over allocates, so expands without reallocating up to some extent.

You could also use `malloc` and `realloc`, which does something similar to vector, but I wouldn't recommend it since you have to manually call `operator new` and destructors.

You could also design your own allocator which does whatever you wish, but it's a bit more work, so I'd just stick with vector.

Comment: There's `uninitialized_move` that could help with `realloc` but itss still bad compared to a vector.

Answer (score -3):

You can use realloc that is available from C language.

memory = (int *) realloc(memory, 10);

It would reallocate from the same address.

Comment: "It would reallocate from the same address." It might or might not. It is not safe for non-POD structures since it does not call constructors nor destructors.

Comment: There is no guarantee `realloc` returns the same address.

Comment: You can't `realloc` memory that's allocated with `new`.

Comment: `malloc`, `calloc` & `realloc` don't call constructors or destructors, so they are usually not suitable for use with C++ objects.

Comment: And if `realloc()` returns `nullptr` in your example, you have a memory leak.